# Unit will not power on or Unit is not power on

Tags: expressions

I am facing this: Unit will not power on.
As I understand it means that certain device we cannot put to working state if we can try to do it right now.

So why do we cannot use  Present Time and say

Unit is not power on.

Any clue?

Comment: "Power" is a verb in this (more specifically, "power on" is a phrasal verb). So it can follow an auxiliary like "will", but cannot follow "is" - that would require a different construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say:

> *The* unit is not *powered* on.

it just refers to the power state at that moment. It could be turned off, but otherwise working correctly if you turn in on later.

> The *unit* will not power on.

This unit will not work, regardless of how you operate it, now or in the future unless some repair action occurs.

Comment: You may also say *The unit does not power on* for the second.

Comment: Or perhaps "The unit is not powering on." This is the equivalent of the "The unit will not power on" that I think the OP may have been reaching for.

Comment: @Catija Your suggestion is close to my native language and understanding. Thank you!